It failed to upgrade the RealmSwift version from v3.20.0 to v10.49.0
Our app uses the v3.20.0 of RealmSwift, I need to upgrade to the latest version during the iOS privacy manifest.
But there is a crash happening:
Thread 1: Fatal error: Failed to initialize Realm: Error Domain=io.realm Code=16 "Database has an unsupported version (9) and cannot be upgraded" UserInfo={Error Name=UnsupportedFileFormatVersion, NSLocalizedDescription=Database has an unsupported version (9) and cannot be upgraded, Error Code=16}
If I uninstall the existing app and then install the latest version of RealmSwift (v10.49.0), the crash mentioned above would not have occurred.

Welcome to SO. Often times you'll find a similar question has been asked so good to do some research before posting questions. Please see this answer and then this comment. Also see the 10.49.2 release as it refers to the privacy manifest.

The developer has answer to me, I can't directly upgrade to v10.49.2 from v3.20.0. I firstly need to upgrade to v10.46.0 then upgrade to v10.49.2.
